# Getting the changed value of an input type number

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I am working with HTML 5 number type and am trying to calculate the difference between the original number and the number upon the change. I have a bunch of inner number fields that add to a master number field. It is for an exam grading page. So I have number values for each question and then a master one for the exam as a whole. For ex. I have 4 number fields all of potential values of 0 through 2 for 4 different questions, and then the master would be however many out of 8 points. Since any number of questions may or may not be on the current page at the time, I'd like to update my master by simply sending it a changed value. For example, if I change a value of 0/2 to 2/2 I would want to send it a +2 to the master and update from that. Is it possible take from change event listener the original value and the new value?

Comment: Nope, you should probably just recompute the total every time an input changes.

Comment: Your question is not very readable, try to paragraph and clearly list questions in bullet.

Comment: IT was easily and simply answered below. There is clearly a question at the end of the context. So tempermental here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by attaching `onchange` listeners to each of your inputs like so:

```
anIndividualInput.onchange = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var delta = input._oldValue ? input.value - input._oldValue : input.value;
  input._oldValue = input.value;
  // Call your master function with the delta
};
```

Comment: You are quite welcome :)